# Destructure withIndex() iterator

Tags: kotlin

Messing around with [destructuring declarations](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/multi-declarations.html) and the following perplexes me:

```
private data class TestData(var i: String, var j: Int) : Any() {}
private var mlist = mutableListOf<TestData>()

fun main(args: Array<String>) {

    mlist.add(TestData("Hi", 5))
    mlist.add(TestData("There", 53))
    mlist.add(TestData("Test", 2345))
    for ((i, v) in mlist.withIndex()) {

       println(i.toString() + " ok " + v.i + " " + v.component2())//Why does this line compile? 

       println("${i::class.qualifiedName}") // Printed classname is Int
   }
}
```

As i understand it the code destructures

```
fun <T> Array<out T>.withIndex(): Iterable<IndexedValue<T>> (source)
```

But why does `v.i` compile? What is going on?

The code outputs:

> 0 ok Hi 5
>   kotlin.Int
>   1 ok There 53
>   kotlin.Int
>   2 ok Test
>   2345
>   kotlin.Int

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your following code

```
for ((i, v) in mlist.withIndex()) {...
```

is equal to

```
for (item in mlist.withIndex()) {
    val i: Int = item.component1() //it is index in your list
    val v: TestData = item.component2()
    ...
```

If you want to get only `TestData` elements, remove `withIndex` call

```
for (item in mlist) {
    val i: String = item.component1()
    val v: Int = item.component2()
    ...
```

To make it work your class should have `operator fun` for mentioned `componentN`. Your `TestData` class have it because you marked it as [`data class`](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/data-classes.html).

And lets return to code line that confusing you

```
println(i.toString() + " ok " + v.i + " " + v.component2())
```

As we already know - `v: TestData`. So `i` here is propery that you mentioned in primary constructor with `var` keyword.

```
private data class TestData(var i: String, var j: Int)
```

Also it can be marked as `val` - in your case it doesn't make a sense, but then you just won't be able to edit this property value ([here](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/classes.html) you can read about constructors).

```
private class TestData(i: String, j: Int) //this won't work in your case
```

Comment: hmmm, that does not make sense with the output i provided? And doesn't explain why I can write `v.i`. i is an iterator which just increases. `v` in my case is `item`, in your case

Comment: Sorry, didn't see `withIndex` at first time. :) Edited answer.

Comment: This answer does not address my question what `v.i` means, syntactically. `i` is not a method, how can I write it like that and it resulting in accessing the first component function of the object? whilst still being an Int? I am very confused

Comment: `v.i` is accessing the `i` property of the `TestData` type, which has nothing at all to do with the variable you've named `i` in the loop.